# How to get all groups a yammer user can post message to?

Tags: yammer

I want to get all groups a yammer user can post message to,I know "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=true" get groups the use belong to,but the results do not include public groups the use does not belong to.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json to get all the groups in your network and parse the list for groups where privacy => public.

Combine that with the list from https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=true and that should be the complete list of groups.